# jquery UI - Adding date to selected date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

It seems a simple thing but i'm unable to solve it and i really need this. **How can i add a date to a selected date, through the SelectedDate event?**

I need to perform a date range limit on 2 datepickers. Once the user set one datepicker the other needs to only allow date equals to the selected date of the first datepicker, plus one month.

Example: if i set '3 of march' on the first calendar, the second must allow only dates greater than '3 of april'.

So far by now i can only get the same selected date or the one i set through `$('#dtpicker').datepicker( "setDate" , '+1m');`. I tried the jquery-ui documentation example, but nothing.

Comment: Have you looked at the example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range ? Seems to do what you want.

Comment: Sorry, but as i said, it didn't work. The example only restricts the selected date, not the selected date plus one month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented similar functionality on two datepickers.

```
function handleDateChange() {
    var dateStart = $('#datepicker-startdate').datepicker("getDate"), 
        dateEnd = $('#datepicker-enddate').datepicker("getDate");
    if (dateStart !== null) {
        dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() + 1);
        $('#datepicker-enddate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateStart);
    }
    if (dateEnd !== null) {
        dateEnd.setDate(dateEnd.getDate() - 1);
        $('#datepicker-enddate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', dateEnd);
    }
 }
```

Use this method in the `onSelect` handler of your datepickers (as init option):

```
$(/*your datepicker selector*/).datepicker({
    // ... other init options
    onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {handleDateChange();}
});
```

I think this is similar to what you need, if not then it should definitely get you on the right track.

Comment: Hey, thanks! As you said it definitely put me on track. You just misunderstood a little parte, as there's no need to restrict the maxDate of the `#datepicker-enddate`, just the minDate. I've just ajusted the section `dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() + 1)` to `dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() + 30)` and it did the trick!

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick for you:

```
var plus_one_month =  '';
var minus_one_month =  '';
$("#from").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function() {
        if($("#to").val() != '') { 
            minus_one_month =  new Date($("#to").val());
            minus_one_month.setMonth(minus_one_month.getMonth() - 1);
        } else {
            minus_one_month =  '';
        }
        return {
            minDate: minus_one_month,
            maxDate: new Date($("#to").val())
        }
    }
});

$("#to").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function() {
        if($("#from").val() != '') { 
            plus_one_month =  new Date($("#from").val());
            plus_one_month.setMonth(plus_one_month.getMonth() + 1);
        } else {
            plus_one_month =  '';
        }
        return {
            minDate: new Date($("#from").val()),
            maxDate: plus_one_month
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/CnHzs/).

Comment: i guess you misunderstood what i want. Once a user selects a data from the `#from` datepicker, the minDate of the `#to` datepicker would be the selected date of `#from` datepicker + 1 month. Anyway, your answer has given me new ways to solve this problem, so thanks.