# jQuery Datepicker setDate - find next work day in Datepicker 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui-datepicker, gravity-forms-plugin

In a gravity form I have been able to disable weekends and public holidays from Datepicker 1 (from date) and Datepicker 2 (to date).

In Datepicker 2 we want to select the first workday three days after the date selected in Datepicker 1.

See: http://returatrv.staging.wpengine.com/bestilling-container-borettslag/

If you select feb 17 in cal1, feb 20 is selected in DP2, which is correct.
The setDate is getDate +3 days.

When setDate ends up on a weekend or disabled date, it should jump to the next work-day.
If feb 19 is selected in DP1, feb 24 should be selected in DP2 (first workday).
How can I use the code already in place (line 9-15) to set setDate to the first non-disabled day in the array?

I have a feeling I could reuse the code in

```
 optionsObj.beforeShowDay = function(date) { ...
```

to change the setDate for DP2.

```
 set_date.setDate(set_date.getDate() + 3); //check if the result is in disabled days / weekends
```

I would really appreciate som help on this ;)
Although many other questions are similar (like [Add days after date is selected excluding weekends and holidays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533519/add-days-after-date-is-selected-excluding-weekends-and-holidays)), I have not been able to solve this.

```
  gform.addFilter('gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function(optionsObj,
    formId, fieldId) {

    if (formId == <?php echo $skjemaID; ?> && fieldId == 7) {

     // Disable holidays and weekends from datapickers
     // Could I use this to find first work-day?
     optionsObj.beforeShowDay = function(date) {

     // array of holidays from external json-source
     currentDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date),
     day = date.getDay();

      return [!(disabledDays.indexOf(currentDate) != -1 || day == 0 ||
        day == 6)];
    };


      optionsObj.minDate = 1;
      optionsObj.onClose = function(dateText, inst) {
        var min_date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText),
            set_date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText),
            end_date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText);

            // set minDate in datepicker 1 to nest day
            min_date.setDate(min_date.getDate() + 1);

            // Find first workday after 3 days
            // Samples of expected behaviour:
            // Select feb 10 in dp1 - show feb 13 in dp2
            // Select feb 12 in dp1 - show feb 17 in dp2
            // Select feb 27 in dp1 - show mar in dp2

            set_date.setDate(set_date.getDate() +3);

            // Check if set_date is in disabledDays or weekend
            // if yes, add a day, check again
            // if not, select set_day in datepicker 2 

        $('#input_<?php echo $skjemaID; ?>_8').datepicker('option',
          'minDate', min_date).datepicker('setDate', set_date);
      };
    }
    return optionsObj;
  });
```

Please help me in the right direction; I have been struggling quite some time with this.

Comment: `I have not been able to solve this.` why not? The `while` approach is the immediate solution I thought about.

Comment: See comment under. Why can't result of `function isInArray(disabledDates, value) {
          return [!(disabledDates.indexOf(value) != -1 || day == 0 || day == 6)];
        }`
be evaluated in if/then or while-loop?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to stop the `while` loop if the data is in `disabledDate`. You just need to not skip also if the date is in disabled. https://jsbin.com/sodidey/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks Mosh Feu for helping me along the way to fix this ;). I basically just needed the following do/while-loop: do {
          set_date.setDate(set_date.getDate() + 1);
        }
        while (!isInArray(disabledDates, set_date));

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `AddBusinessDays` function from the linked "similar question" and replace the call to `noWeekendsOrHolidays` with your `beforeShowDay` function. You would also need to pass in the start date instead of using today.

Comment: I have added a function that evaluates if setDate is within disabledDays, but although it returns True or False in console. I can't get a loop to stop when it is FALSE.

     `   function isInArray(disabledDates, value) {
          return [!(disabledDates.indexOf(value) != -1 || day == 0 || day == 6)];
        }

        if (check != 'true') {
          console.log( 'Check in first loop: ' + check );
          set_date.setDate(set_date.getDate() + 1);
          var check = isInArray(disabledDates, set_date);
        } // Does not work

Answer (score 0):

After much testing I was able to find the problem and solve this.
The final code (replacing optionsObj.onClose = function(dateText, inst))

```
optionsObj.onClose = function(dateText, inst) {

    var min_date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', dateText),
        set_date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', dateText);

  function isInArray(disabledDates, dateToCheck) {
   const day = dateToCheck.getDay();
    return !(disabledDates.indexOf(dateToCheck) != -1 || day === 0 || day == 6);
    } 

    min_date.setDate(min_date.getDate() + 1);
    set_date.setDate(set_date.getDate() + 2);

    do {
      set_date.setDate(set_date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    while (!isInArray(disabledDates, set_date));

    $('#input_<?php echo $skjemaID; ?>_8').datepicker('option',
      'minDate', min_date).datepicker('setDate', set_date);
  };
```

Thanks for help, the JSbin from Mosh Feu made me see what was wrong.